# Is there a way to use a single "print", with multiple statements, and get the result in which statements are one below the other

Tags: python

I want the result as
you win
you won the medal
how can I get these sentences one below the other in a single print?
print("You WIN!!"
"you won the medal!!")
this doesn't work

Comment: "\n" is a newline

Answer (score 2):

```
print("you win","you won the medal",sep="\n")
```

is another way

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n` to separate lines:

```py
print("You WIN!!\nyou won the medal!!")
```